# How to implement a compile time counter

Tags: c++, c++14

Is it possible to implement a compile time counter?
I want something like this (The initial value should be 0):

```
int main () {
  constexpr int a = next ();
  constexpr int b = next ();
  constexpr int c = next ();

  static_assert (a == 0 && b == a+1 && c == b+1, "");
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of anything like that in the C++ standard. gcc, though, does offer a [`__COUNTER__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros) preprocessor macro.

Comment: http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/ 
but I am not sure I would use it in any non-toy project